# Space Complexity with O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, space-complexity

So, Everbody is familiar with constant `O(1)` or Linear `O(N)` Space Complexity.

But I have a question that, is there any case when Space Complexity of an Algorithm is proportional to `O(NLogn)` or `O(N^2)`. If that's possible, what is the advantage of it.

P.S.- I have researched over various sites but didn't got any satisfactory solution.

Comment: You should move this to discussion

Comment: Any algorithm which returns a result of size `f(N)` takes at least `O(f(N))` additional space (provided  of course the result does not share space with the input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost any algorithm can be made to use `O(N^2)` memory. Consider some `f(a,b)` where `0 < a,b < N` and `f` is expensive to calculate. To reduce runtime an obvious solution is to use a look up table of size `N * N` with pre calculated results. Such kind of trade-off between runtime and memory usage can be made very often.

In general, algorithms that are using matrices typically take `N*N` memory to store the matrices. For example to rotate a point in `N=3` dimensions, you can use a `3x3` rotation matrix.